# Using a gateway for LAN chaining devices

Tags: linux, lan, gateway

I am trying to create a LAN chain between 3 linux devices (A, B and C). The goal is to be able to send data from both devices B and C to device A.

```
A <-- B <-- C    (configuration B --> A <-- C is not possible)
```

All devices have static ip adresses assigned:

```
A: eth0 - 10.0.0.10/24
B: eth0 - 10.0.0.11/24
B: eth1 - 10.0.1.11/24
C: eth0 - 10.0.1.12/24
```

allowing connections between A to B and B to C. If device B could be configured as a gateway, it could allow a connection between A and C as well. I am searching for a way to make such a chain operational, but I haven't been successful thus far. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Some extra details:

```
System OS: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Device B has two interfaces
```

Comment: You can create a forwarding rule inside your package firewall.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming and would be better served at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux

Comment: @arkascha, you mean setting the ip_forward value to 1? Because only doing that isn't sufficient right?